# How to forward port at windows azure cloud servers

Tags: azure

Hi i just tried windows azure cloud servers.

downloaded and run apache it works on localhost but can't access from internet

should i port forward do anything special for able to make *.cloudapp.net work like a web server

what i am missing?

Comment: Have you configured endpoints properly so that port 80 is opened on your VM?

Comment: yes :(
Name Protocol Public port Private port Load balanced

 RemoteDesktop TCP 3389 3389 NO
 web TCP 80 80 NO

Answer (score 4):

what exactly did you try? Azure Virtual Machine? Azure Worker Role? I guess an Azure Virtual Machine using Linux since you are talking about Apache. You need to add an [TCP Endpoint on port 80](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/how-to-guides/setup-endpoints/).

Comment: just installed apache and binded endpoint to 80 port. but still i can make remote connections :(

Comment: Have you added an ENDPOINT for your virtual machine as instructed in the article I provided?

Comment: and i can access from localhost , "Listen 80" is the binding configuration of httpd.conf is it right?

Answer (score 4):

You only need to configure an endpoint to do that.

In your azure panel -> Virtual Machines -> your_machine_name -> Endpoints. You should see something like this:

[image: Endpoint configuration]

Public port -> 80 (if you want to serve your_machine_name.cloudapp.net)

Private port -> (your server listening port)

Comment: Thank you. How to do it in own Windows Server ?

Answer (score 2):

This has changed recently. Click "All Resources" then click your network security group:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyK9v.png)

Then click "Inbound Security Rules". Click 'Add'. Click 'Add'. Then fill in the details. For 'Destination Port Range' you should put whatever port Apache is listening on, probably 80. Example: [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7tSy.png)

Click 'Okay' and you're good to go!

Comment: This isn't port forwarding, as far as I can tell security rules is just a simple firewall configuration

Comment: Don't forget to poke a hole in your firewall on the same port!