# Port forwarding in Azure

Tags: tomcat, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a piece of software running in Windows Server on an Azure VM via Tomcat on port 8080. I have been trying for a while to forward this port so that I can access this software form another pc by navigating to :8080/

I have never forwarded a port before but I have read the various posts
such as here
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/
and here
[How to forward port at windows azure cloud servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746649/how-to-forward-port-at-windows-azure-cloud-servers)

I have tried setting up an endpoint using the identical public and private ports and navigating to `vmaddress.cloudapp.net:8080/...` but it does not work.

Endpoint I have set up:

[image: Endpoint]

Comment: Is the VM OS Windows Server?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include a screenshot of your endpoint settings? Also can you verify whether you can access localhost:8080 when RDP'd into the VM? Did you configure tomcat to listen for remote connections?

Comment: @DavidMakogon added the screenshot. And yes I can access it through localhost on the vm, that is how I currently use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming the VM OS is Windows Server 2012**, you may need to create a rule on the OS firewall to allow the inbound traffic.

While [this example](https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/managing-the-windows-server-2012-firewall) is on Rackspace & not specific to port 8080, you can substitute your particulars, where appropriate. Just RDP into the VM and make the changes as shown.

Comment: This isn't necessary. There are no ports blocked by default via Azure VM's firewall.

Comment: I'm talking about the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" built into the server OS, not an Azure function. I just provisioned an A0 VM with WS12R2 Datacenter. By default, the firewall is enabled and does not have an inbound rule for TCP 8080.

Comment: @CavRecon Sorted! I can now connect to the port. Thanks! Out of interest how would I restrict access tot he port based on IP address, within windows firewall I mean?

Comment: @CavRecon never mind I have sorted that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

vmaddress:8080 (if vmaddress=a private ip) would work only when you are trying to access this from an instance which is within the same VNet as that of the instance on which you have created this endpoint.
If you want to access this through internet or from an instance from some other VNet then try accessing through *CloudServiceVIP*:8080 or using that instance's Public IP (provided you have reserved one for that instance) - *VMPublicIPAddress*:8080

Comment: thanks for the reply. So I should set up a VNet and link the relevant VM's to it? Neither of the options you gave for accessing it from a different VNet worked either unfortunately.

Comment: Apologies! In order to access from anywhere please use your Cloud Service's VIP available from Dashboard like CloudServiceVIP:8080. I have edited my answer also.